# Please rename [aurelia-2] to [aurelia2]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

I just created the tag [aurelia-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aurelia-2) and then immediately noticed that other libraries in the community use a convention which [aurelia2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aurelia2) would fit better. Would you please help me get the tag updated?